# How to change the height of an element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to modify the height of a div element in a Javascript function. The height is initially
set to 50px in the style section. Neither of the attempts shown below have any effect. I would appreciate your help on this. Thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            setHeight();
        }

        function setHeight() {
            var testElement = document.getElementById("test");
            testElement.style.offsetHeight = 200;
            testElement.offsetHeight = 200;
        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" style="height:50px;border-style:solid;border-width:thin;">
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `offsetHeight` is not a css property, but `height` is. Consider using `element.style.height`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Your suggestion works! Why can I set and get element.style.height if it is not supposed to exist? Does the system create properties when I try to access them if they are not already defined? Also, element.offsetHeight does exist and is set to the correct initial height of the element but when I try to write to it there is no effect. Is this a read-only property? If so is there a doc you can point me to that describes this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not supposed to exist"? `style.height` is a CSS property defined by CSS, whereas `.offsetHeight` is a JavaScript property and is calculated dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, type. I meant so ask, Why can I set and get element.style.offsetHeight if it is not supposed to exist?

Comment: `offsetHeight` is not a CSS property so it doesn't exist on the `style` property, but _it is_ a property on the element itself. `element.offsetHeight` exists, but it is read-only. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

Comment: Yes, I understand now that offsetHeight is not part of the style property. I am confused by the fact that my code was able to write a value of 200 to element.style.offsetHeight and read it back even though it does not exist. Coming from a C++ and C# background this is very strange behavior. It seems the system created the non-existent property when I first wrote to it because I was able to read it back again (the reading back is not shown in my posted example).

Comment: In JS you can define properties on pretty much any object.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `style.height`

```
testElement.style.height = '200px';
```